# How to find my DHCP server IP address via a command prompt in Windows?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

Linux has easy commands to find the DHCP server IP address via a command prompt.

Is there anything for Windows?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The DHCP server used to obtain an address is included in the output of `ipconfig /all`.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

```
ipconfig /all | findstr /C:"DHCP Server"
```

Answer (score 7):

If your computer has static IP then the `ipconfig /all` will not show the DHCP server on your network. In this case you can use the following command line to display it.

`netsh dhcp show server`

Comment: On my system, `netsh dhcp show server` gives the name of my domain controller. I tried to find the running dhcp server on the DC but could not. `ipconfig /all` showed that my dhcp server was actually a Cisco device. Why the discrepancy between netsh and ipconfig?

Comment: It's possible that they're both right. Likely the DHCP server that `ipconfig /all` reported was the the default gateway for your network and was a DHCP relay.  As such, it would listen for DHCP request broadcasts and relay them to the configured DHCP server, which could reasonably have been the domain controller.